# I want to move 2d object only horizontally by touch in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I implemented a touch drag.

But I can not move only horizontally.

I would expect to limit it to if, but I do not know what to do after that.

Here is my code.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

 public class Draggable : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
 {

     public void OnBeginDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
     {
         Debug.Log ("OnBeginDrag");
     }

     public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
     {
         Debug.Log ("OnBeginDrag");
         //this.transform.position = eventData.position;
         GetComponent<Transform> ().position = eventData.position;
     }

     public void OnEndDrag (PointerEventData evnetData)
     {
         Debug.Log ("OnEndDrag");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call GetComponent for transform.
If the code you were using works and you just want horizontal drag, something like this should work.

```
var currentPos = transform.position;    
transform.position = new Vector3(eventData.position.x, currentPos.y, currentPos.z);
```

Comment: This code is c#. You are probably misguided by var. You can change var->Vector3 if you prefer it.